# Is using several '.filter' calls on a big array bad for performance?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wrote this piece of code to filter an array of words. I wrote a filter function for every type of word I want to filter out and apply them sequentially to the array:

```
  const wordArray = rawArray.filter(removeNonDomainWords)
                            .filter(removeWordsWithDigits)
                            .filter(removeWordsWithInsideNonWordChars)
                            .filter(removeEmptyWords)
                            .filter(removeSearchTerm, term)
                            .map(word => replaceNonWordCharsFromStartAndEnd(word))
```

This code iterates over the whole array six times if I am not mistaken.

**Wouldn't it be more efficient to write one (more complex, yet still easy in my scenario) filter function that logically combines the filter functions to achieve the same result?**

I learned about filter in the context of Functional Programming which is supposed to make my code shorter and faster. That's why I probably didn't question what I was writing, thinking 'I am doing FP, this gotta be good'.

Thanks!

Comment: you can use an `||` operator to chain up all those `removeXX` functions in a single filter.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I had in mind. But is it going to improve performance? If so, why?

Comment: It's about the cost of multiple checks per item with single iteration and single results array creation against single check per item with multiple iteration and multiple results array creation. I would place my bet on the first because the `||` operator would not invoke the remaining checks once it meets a `true` value and this will save a lot of redundant function calls.

Comment: I see, so the iterations themselves are not costy, just the unnecessary checks that would fall away if the (lazy-evaluating) `||` operator was used.

Comment: It all boils down to, 6 shrinking iterations in each you instantiate a smaller results array and assign values against a single iteration in which you instantiate a single result array and fill. Which one do you think is faster?

Comment: I guess the one-iteration solution ?! (Feeling like a student who isn't sure what the teacher wants to hear..) :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, it *does* iterate six times, but not necessarily on the whole initial array. Each time it is filtered it becomes smaller. It would be more effective to have one filter method, but the difference might not be as great as you expect.

If you still want to use this solution, you can increase the performance by using the most selective (that is the filter that is expected filter out the most) first. That way, the following arrays will be smaller and there will be less to iterate through.

As @Redu points out (in comments) you can chain your filters using the `||` operator. This will make sure you only do one iteration.

---

The reason behind this is that `Array.prototype.filter` returns a new array. Compare this with the Java `Stream` API, that returns a stream, and thus can go "depth first" through the call list. The down side of this is that you need a terminal operation in the end, to "collect" your result.

In javascript

```
rawArray.filter(x)
```

iterates the `rawArray` and returns a new filtered array - which can in turn be filtered, or used as it is. It will result in a call to `x` for *each* of the elements in `rawArray`.

In Java the equivalent would be

```
rawArray.stream().filter(x)
```

which would actually not do anything at all at this point. No calls to `x` would be done. The return value would be a `Stream`, that can be used later. It can be further filtered, but it is not until the values are collected in some way - with a *terminal operation* - that calls are made.

Lets compare javascript

```
rawArray.filter(x).filter(y).length
```

to Java

```
rawArray.stream().filter(x).filter(y).count()
```

In javascript, this would first iterate over all of the elements of `rawArray`, calling `x` for each of them, and store the result in an intermediate array. Then the javascript engine would iterate over all of the elements of the intermediate array, calling `y` for each element, and store the result in a second intermediate array, which it would then check the size of.

In Java, the snippet would result in the VM iterating over the elements of `rawArray`, first calling `x`, and, if `x` is `true`, then calling `y` on each element, and, if still `true` incrementing the counter. There would be no intermediate arrays, and only one iteration over the dataset.

Functional programming is interesting, and when used properly, it creates less code that is less complex and ideally perhaps even a bit easier to read, but it does hand over a lot of responsibility to the framework (or engine or VM or whatever), and it is important to realize that seemingly similar code, while *behaving* similarly, can *perform* vastly differently in different environments.

Comment: I understand what you mean, and this is definitely a point to consider. But in  my case the filtering is not affecting the size of the array. what I want to know is if the iterating itself takes a lot of time and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: @Flip What is the point of filtering if you're not expecting to shrink the array?

Comment: It is shrinking, but if the filtered words make out just 1-5% of the arrays size then the effects are not that big, are they?

Comment: Thanks for the extra edit, Bex. As stated below, I will need some time to fully understand the topic and thus be able to mark the best answer.

Comment: @Bex did you ever test this ? I have tried few tests with 3x .filter() vs 1x filter & those filter separated with || and it did not make any difference what so ever in ram usage or in execution time.

Answer (score 4):

As others have answered: your chain will loop over the (filtered) data for every `.filter` call, which can hurt performance, but probably won't, unless you're modifying/filtering thousands of strings.

If you don't want to compromise on performance *nor* readability, you could create your own filter wrapper that supports both chaining and lazy evaluation.

The example below shows a wrapper that "remembers" the filter method you pass to it, but only calls them once you say you're done.

```js
const ArrayFilter = (arr, pred) => ({
  filter: pred
    ? (newPred) => ArrayFilter(arr, x => pred(x) && newPred(x))
    : (newPred) => ArrayFilter(arr, newPred),
  execute: (mapper) => mapper 
    ? arr.filter(pred)
    : arr.filter(pred).map(mapper)
});


// Some test data
const oneToFifty = Array.from(Array(50), (_, i) => i);

// ArrayFilter allows for a chained syntax, but only loops over the data
// once and only runs filters when needed
console.log(
  ArrayFilter(oneToFifty)
    .filter(x => x % 3 === 0)
    .filter(x => x < 25)
    .filter(x => x > 10)
    .execute(n => `Result: ${n}`)
);
```

---

**Edit**, to be completely honest, it's actually quite hard to get a noticeable performance gain using the lazy filter I've shown above... In the snippet below, I checked two types of filters against an array of 1.000.000 random numbers. For almost all of the cases, the "naive" approach of just chaining `Array#filter` beats my custom wrapper.

General rule: the lazy `execute` approach only makes sense for filter collections that remove only a few elements from large sets of data.

If anybody can think of other test cases to throw into the mix, I'd be very interested to try the out!

```js
const ArrayFilter = (arr, pred) => ({
  filter: pred
    ? (newPred) => ArrayFilter(arr, x => pred(x) && newPred(x))
    : (newPred) => ArrayFilter(arr, newPred),
  execute: (mapper) => mapper 
    ? arr.filter(pred)
    : arr.filter(pred).map(mapper)
});


// Some test data, with at least one 0
const million = [0].concat(
  Array.from(Array(999999), Math.random)
);

// Filters that keep removing approx
// 100.000 values until 0
const minusNFilters = [
  x => x <= 0.9,
  x => x <= 0.7,
  x => x <= 0.6,
  x => x <= 0.5,
  x => x <= 0.4,
  x => x <= 0.3,
  x => x <= 0.2,
  x => x <= 0.1,
  x => x <= 0.0
];

// Filters that keep removing 50% of the remaining
// items
const fiftyPFilters = [
  x => x <= 1 / 2,
  x => x <= 1 / 4,
  x => x <= 1 / 8,
  x => x <= 1 / 16,
  x => x <= 1 / 32,
  x => x <= 1 / 64,
  x => x <= 1 / 128,
  x => x <= 1 / 256,
  // Final state
  x => x <= 0
];

const map = x => `Result: ${x}`;

const timed = (label, fn) => {
  console.time(label);
  fn();
  console.timeEnd(label);
};

// Some tests
// For these filters, the ArrayFilter tends to
// be just a bit faster
timed(
  "method   : Regular\nsize     : 1000000 items\nfilters  : -n\nms       ",
  () => minusNFilters
    .reduce((xs, f) => xs.filter(f), million)
    .map(map)
);

timed(
  "method   : ArrayFilter\nsize     : 1000000 items\nfilters  : -n\nms       ",
  () => minusNFilters
    .reduce(
      (af, f) => af.filter(f), 
      ArrayFilter(million))
    .execute(map)
);

// For these filters, the ArrayFilter is usually
// slower
timed(
  "method   : Regular\nsize     : 1000000 items\nfilters  : -50%\nms       ",
  () => fiftyPFilters
    .reduce((xs, f) => xs.filter(f), million)
    .map(map)
);

timed(
  "method   : ArrayFilter\nsize     : 1000000 items\nfilters  : -50%\nms       ",
  () => fiftyPFilters
    .reduce(
      (af, f) => af.filter(f), 
      ArrayFilter(million))
    .execute(map)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100% }
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort! I will need some time to fully understand the topic and thus be able to identify the best answer.